# With Next.js React Server Component, with no client components, how to show error from Form

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, server-action

Looking at the example [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations) in the Next.js docs, I want to be able to show the error generated in the Server Action.

Here is the code snippet they show.

Basically, my question is, assume my "mutate data" has a try/catch with the catch having an error, how can I get that data back to the form so the browser user knows that an error occurred and what it was.

I get how to do this with client components, but I'm wanting to do this per this example in the docs.

```
export default function Page() {
  async function create(formData: FormData) {
    'use server'

    // mutate data
    // revalidate cache
   }
return <form action={create}>...</form>
}
```

Comment: useFormState is the way forward but you have to change your server component to a client component. Another way to display the error message is to add the error message to a cookie and read that cookie. But using cookies may not be the best option

Comment: useFormState (in the future called useFormAction) will be used to display field errors or toast messages. Here is an example implementation: https://www.robinwieruch.de/next-forms/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible right now without using some kind of outside data store (something like redis) to communicate back over.

The `useFormState` was specifically made to solve this issue of communication from a server action back to a component, and, because it is a hook, it can only be used in a client component.

Comment: Honestly insane that a popular modern web framework does not support posting data to a form and returning a page with modified data without javascript.

Comment: next.js is always developing. to me they are always on alpha version.